# IIS Worker Process не позволяет удалить файл

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, файлы, iis

Проблема состоит в том, что IIS не даёт приложению на C# удалить обычный архив, выпадает ошибка:

**The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**

Пробую руками удалить его из файловой системы, пишет, что файл используется процессом IIS Worker Process и не может быть изменён. Как только я приостанавливаю IIS, файл становится доступен для удаления.
Пробовала дать все права на доступ к файлу, но это не помогло.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема, и как её решить?

Comment: Мжет не закрытые конекшены на запись/чтение остаются во время работы приложения?

Comment: @Павел Зайцев, после каждого использования файла вызывается функция "DIspose", которая согласно документации на MSDN, должна высвобождать файл для дальнейшего использования другими процессами.

Comment: Я думаю что проблема, все таки, в открытии файла. Приведи пример использования файла, который не удаляется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш файл удерживается процессом, т.к. в коде есть окрытый handle на этот файл.

Вы можете переписать код так что бы все открываемые файлы были в операторе `using` или корректно вызывать метод `Dispose` у открываемых файлов (например в секции `try finally`)

Так же вы можете переименовать файл через PInvoke используя специальную функцию  - [MoveFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240) указав на входе флаг `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT` и задав имя в `NULL` и тогда ваш файл будет удален после перезагрузки системы.